# Как исправить проблему с регулятором оборотов двигателя arduino?

Tags: arduino

```
#include "GyverMotor.h"
GMotor motor(DRIVER2WIRE, 8, 9);

void setup() {
  motor.setMode(FORWARD);
  motor.setSpeed(150);
  
}
void loop() {
  
}
```

Это код из библиотеки "GyverMotor". Собрал всё по схеме, но не работает "setSpeed". Вместо нормалной регулировки оборотов, оно мне постоянно выдаёт один и тож-же результат -- максимальная скорость.

Вот схема подключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На схеме у вас трехпроводное подключение (`DRIVER3WIRE`), а в коде двухпроводное

Comment: Поменял тип подключения и ничего не поменялось. Я вот думаю, что возможно у меня на кинайской arduino нет поддержки ШИМ сигнала, потому что на ней нет никаких обозначений ввиде символа тильда (~)

Comment: Всем спасибо. Я поняв в чём была проблема. У меня был не драйвер TB6612, а драйвер DRV8833. 
Они практически идентические, но информации по подключению и прошивке практически нет(